# How can I retrieve all files sizes of a folder based on file name and/or extension?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a form where the user navigates to a specific folder. The folder they navigate to will have many folders inside it, and within several levels of folders there will be a zip file named "file.zip". So this means there are going to be many folders all which have inside them a "file.zip". I want to scan the chosen folder for all of these "file.zip" files. I will eventually be looking for only those "file.zip" files that have a size of 0kb or is empty. I imagine that I will need to use LINQ to return a list of the files in the parent folder like this:

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtbxOldFolder.Text)
                      .Select(f => Path.GetFiles(f))
                      .ToArray();
```

But I also need their respective sizes so I can later create a list of the directory of any zip files that is empty or shows a size of 0kb. I'm thinking that perhaps there is a way to return the directory AND the size of each file based on name (file.zip) so that I can later go through the array and create a log of the directories for those file.zips that are empty/have a size of 0kb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var directory = @"c:\myfolder";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "file.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Select(name => new FileInfo(name))
.Where(f => f.Length == 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm uncertain how to verify if this works as it doesn't seem to actually write to an array unless I misunderstand the var call. I need to write this info to a logfile and open it, here's how I do it and here's what I'm getting.
File.WriteAllText(folderLog, files.ToString());
and it shows "System.IO.FileInfo[]" in my log?

Comment: the files variable contains an array of objects of type "FileInfo", which represent files, which are named "file.zip" and have zero length inside your folder. To open any of them, use FileInfo.Open(), FileInfo.OpenRead() or FileInfo.OpenText(). The FullName contains the full path to file. FileInfo.Length contains file length.